# Handling object deserialisation after changing namespace

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm wondering is there any way to handle deserialisation after changing a classes, namespace?

At the moment I'm having to do an edit replace on the text value of the XML replacing old namespace with new namespace.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always a tricky one. Unless you can guarantee that the class won't change, then it's probably best to find another approach to serializing.

However, to answer the question, you could have a `Version` property of the class (or put it in a base class if you have many). You'll need to remember to increment this whenever you change the class.

Then you could have a series of "migrations", which would know how to transform the XML from one version to the next. When you want to deserialize, first load the file as XML, apply the migrations in turn (as there may have been several changes since the file was created), and then deserialize the now transformed XML.

Comment: Nothing seems very clean here does it?  The answer is probably impossible (e.g. know what you need in advance, and also know what you are going to need in the future)